# SQL Trigger to Application

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2019, connection-string

I have a SQL Server database connected to an app the organizes shipping. Like a calendar Schedule. Is there a way to pick up a trigger, in my case Update, in the app when one user makes a change, so that all other apps connected to the database update to the update trigger call? just so to keep all the apps updated to most reason data. I'm using SQL connection string.

```
Public Shared Sub Load(ByRef MyCollect As List(Of PAPaintSchedule), Filter As String, OrderBy As String)
        MyCollect = New List(Of PAPaintSchedule)

        Dim CMDValue As String = $"SELECT * FROM {TableName}"
        If Filter IsNot Nothing Then CMDValue &= $" WHERE {Filter}"
        If OrderBy IsNot Nothing Then CMDValue &= $" ORDER BY {OrderBy}"
        CMDValue &= ";"

        If SQLCon.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then SQLCon.Open()

        Dim CMD As New SqlCommand(CMDValue, SQLCon)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader()
        Try
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While reader.Read()
                    Dim LF As New PAPaintSchedule With {.Id = reader(0),
                                            .PaintDate = reader(1),
                                            .Total = reader(2),
                                            .Notes = reader(5)}

                    LF.HasChanges = False
                    MyCollect.Add(LF)
                End While

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not SQLCon.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then SQLCon.Close()
        Finally
            reader.Close()
            CMD.Dispose()
            If Not SQLCon.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then SQLCon.Close()
        End Try

        If Not SQLCon.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then SQLCon.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: There are ways, but its a big topic, far too big for a question. You need to go research the options, choose one, have a go, and then ask a question when stuck.

Comment: Your current code has a number of issues: **dangerously open to SQL injection**, also you should not cache connection object, and you should dispose connection and reader with `Using` blocks

Comment: There are a number of strategies,  and will depend a huge amount on exactly how you want to manage it.  Questions you need to ask for example, What happens if a user is in the process of editing a record when updates are triggered? What is the purpose of this updating?  Is it something that can be managed by periodic polling from the client?

Comment: Does each app have its own database? Are you asking for a way to replicate some or all data between databases, or are you asking for a way for apps to sendo notifications to each other, or is this a single database, but you just want the client apps to refresh?

Comment: Agreed, that my SQL injections are open, I need to rewrite the loading function. I wrote that to present the question.

Comment: The app is for in business use only, but eventually i'd like to include it on smart phone/tablets.  I was working on a chat service that would send the Update/Inserted commands to other apps as needed. At the same time, I could Include a messaging service for users to post info for other users. The problem is it's on a private network. If I could bypass the chat service and use the database to let each app know changes were made, It would be a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks for ur input in this guys, each comment has been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is an adage that is sometimes mistaken for a joke: *There are only two difficulties in computer science: cache coherency and naming things*.  Your question is about the former.

The problem of keeping clients up to date with the most recent data is not really a database problem.  Some client libraries do offer some mechanisms, but in general the problem is orthogonal to updating the database.  It's about notifying peers, which is a messaging problem.  (You could, for instance, handle the problem by automated email.)  The greater the number of peers, and the more spread out they are around the world, the more time and space and the speed of light present obstacles to just the definition of "most recent".

Within the database, the problem is better defined: you usually do not want a situation where *last write wins*.  If two clients read the same record, and one updates it, and then the other one updates it, you don't want the second update to succeed unless it incorporates the first update. Instead of *read-write-write*, you want *read-write, read-write*.

In SQL, this is addressed generally through *isolation levels*.  In the simplest case, the first reader can block the second until he's done, as part of a *transaction*.  The problem is, what is "done"?  After lunch? Because that's usually not acceptable, programmers of interactive applications are advised never to keep a transaction open while the user has control.

The workaround, developed at the dawn of the database revolution, is *optimistic concurrency*: multiple reads are permitted, but each write is careful to not to overwrite intervening updates.  This usually works (hence, optimistic) because normally users aren't competing to update the same record.

One implementation requires no DBMS support.  Reads happen outside transactions (no blocking). The user enters modified data into the application.  The application also keeps a copy of the original record.  To update the database, the application first reads the record again -- this time in a transaction, blocking others -- and compares the newly read record to the original.  If they match, the updated values are applied, and the transaction closed.

Note well, this *read-compare-update* process can't simply be a **select** followed by **update** using the DBMS's default isolation level.  Rather, it takes place inside the DBMS as part of an  **UPDATE** statement that restricts the update to "rows" (usually just 1) where the original data are still present in the database.  The DBMS reports how many rows were affected and, if that answer is zero, the application infers that the row had been changed meanwhile. Recovery is application-dependent, but an obvious tactic is to present the user with the record as it now stands, and try again.

To facilitate *optimistic concurrency*, many DBMSs provide a built-in concurrency control datatype, such the *timestamp* in SQL Server, which changes value automatically whenever the row is updated.  The "was it changed?" question can then be answered by comparing to a single value, rather than the whole row.

In case this all seems hopelessly clumsy or theoretical, consider this: it's how the stock market works.  If you issue an order to buy stock X at price Y, where Y is the current price on your screen right now (whatever "current" and "now" mean), no one is waiting for you, nor are you waiting for anyone else.  You don't even share a system.  Unless you are paying huge fees, any price updates you might be receiving are intentionally delayed.  Your order arrives amidst the crush of all other orders and, unlike the usual case, many others might well be competing for the same X @ Y.  Buy and sell orders are arranged by time and price as they arrive.  Only way down at the bottom, far from the touch of human hands, do transactions make sure each update is working only with the "most recent" data.

Comment: You mention that the application keeps a copy of the original record but that the _read-compare-update_ happens in the DBMS. Can you elaborate on this? Would the application provide its copy of the record while calling the UPDATE statement?

Comment: Thanks guys for ur input! I was away for the day yesterday. I'm using a single database that multiple apps connect to. The apps connect to retrieve data and then dispose the connection after retrieving the data.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville, basically, yes, the statement uses an existential quantifier:  `UPDATE table SET values WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE <a=old_a and b=old_b etc>)`.  That causes the DBMS to update the row only if the correlated subquery (containing the previously selected values) is satisfied, meaning the row hasn't been updated since it was last read. If it *has* been modified, the subquery matches zero rows, and no rows are updated.  The caller must check how many rows were affected to know whether or not the update was applied.